# I can see some events is running in my mysql database. But I couldn't see the source code. How can I see the event code which is exists in database?

Tags: mysql

I see two events is running in mysql database. One is once in a day and another once in a hour. I need to get the source code of these two events. How  can I get event source code? I need to alter that event. That's why I really need to get the existing event source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [show create event](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/show-create-event.html) command in mysql to retrieve the sql code run by the event.